# Autocomplete script returns id in JSON

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using a auto complete to my textbox. I want the ID retrieved to my json should be store in hidden textbox id="special" saved as comma separated. Suppose what so ever value I select in autosuggestion its id should get store in hidden textbox separated as comma.
How can I minimize this piece of code. I am new with jquery.

```
$(".artist").focus().autocomplete( '<?php echo HTTP_PATH . '/artists/getArtistList'; ?>', {
            multiple: true,
            mustMatch: true,
            matchContains: true,
            scroll: true,
            minChars: 0,
            autoFill: true,
            dataType: "json",
            parse: function(data) {
                return $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return { data: item, value: item.name, result: item.name};
                });
            },
            formatItem: function(item) {
                return item.name;
            },
            formatResult: function(item) {
                return item.id;
            },
            formatMatch: function(item) {
                return item.name;
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using jQuery UI or are you using a different plugin? If you are using jQuery UI then you can refer to http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp